# Firefox is not initializing from jenkins. GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays error is returned

Tags: selenium, firefox, jenkins

Firefox is not starting when I try to execute selenium script from jenkins. However it is working fine when I execute this from directly without using jenkins. While executing this from jenkins it returns following error:

org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available display

Also I set the environment variable DISPLAY=:0.0 ,But still getting same error.

Operating System:   **Ubuntu**
Selelenium version: **2.53**
Firefox version:    **46.0**
Programming lang:   **java**

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find any answer? I have the same problem.